# How to measure only ACT part of a unit test in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

As we all know unit test consists of three A's: **A**rrange, **A**ct, **A**ssert.
The problem is that Visual Studio measures unit test elapsed time for all the three A's.

I am sure that it should measure only the Act time.

So is it possible to measure only Act time?

Comment: Probably if you measure it yourself with the [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) within the test.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you measure it yourself with the [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) within the test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Some_Test() {
    //Arrange
    //...
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    //Act
    stopWatch.Start();
    //...
    stopWatch.Stop();

    //Assert        
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    //...
}
```

The ting is that there is no way for the actual test adapter to know what is your *Act* in the test so having visual studio being able to actually measure it is almost impossible.

Comment: Of course this is a good option just to measure the time, but can I integrate it into the tests infrastructure: tests window, reports, etc.?

Comment: What I look for is some interface in test adapter, which will allow me to tell: start counting here, stop counting here. Currently I solve it with a Stopwatch and some additional code, which provides extra data from the test, not something readable by test adapter. But this is a work around, which, of course, should not be in the tests' code (which should be kinda pure).